# AC_CHECK_LIB with fltk

Tags: c, autotools, fltk

What is a good function to use in the AC_CHECK_LIB for the fltk library? 
I have a project that uses fltk, and I would like to setup a configure.ac to check that the library exists. AC_CHECK_LIB takes the library name, plus a function name to check. I would like a C function is possible to simplify things, and a function that exists in all / most releases/version of fltk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should not use `AC_CHECK_LIB` in the first place.

Use `AC_CHECK_LIBS`.

Documentation on how to do this is here:  https://autotools.io/autoconf/finding.html

Comment: Thanks i'll give this a try. You deliberately waited a month to answer this so you could get some kind of badge right?

Comment: I don't pay attention to badges. Just saw it around and replied :)